# Getting year from a field of type character varying

Tags: postgresql, intersection

I did an intersection between two tables and the resulting field has an `sdate` of type character varying (29). An example value is 2012-01-13 05:00:00. How do I get just the year from it?

I want to use a postgres query. I tried `extract('year' from sdate)` but it didn't work because it's type char varying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TO_CHAR function to get the year from your date, even if they are characters.

In this example, I've created a subquery that converts your strings to timestamp formatted data.

Then I use the T0_CHAR(datefield, 'format') to get the year:

```
select  

TO_CHAR(datequery.date, 'yyyy')

from (

select '2012-01-13 05:00:00'::timestamp 

as date) as datequery
```

Which results in:

```
2012
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either convert the String field to a DateTime field and use DateTime functions to extract the year or use string functions to subset the string and extract the year. The second approach seems simpler.

In postresql use this query:

```
select substring('2012-01-13 05:00:00' from 1 for 4);
```

or for the whole field:

```
select substring(sdate from 1 for 4) from your_table;
```